# Ignore hidden files when using list.files in R

Tags: r

I wish to copy an xlsx file from a really really slow network drive to my RStudio project directory.

Although my file name in my specified file directory is unique, when I run `list.files()` in that directory I get two versions of the same file. I am assuming the second is a hidden version of the file.

```
current_folder <- "//server/address1/address2/address3/Info/more/and more/and more again/R Code"

new_folder <- getwd()

list_of_files <- list.files(path = current_folder, 
                            pattern = "class_xwalk_new.xlsx", 
                            all.files = FALSE, 
                            recursive = FALSE,
                            full.names = TRUE)

> list_of_files
[1] "//server/address1/address2/address3/Info/more/and more/and more again/R Code/~$class_xwalk_new.xlsx"
[2] "//server/address1/address2/address3/Info/more/and more/and more again/R Code/class_xwalk_new.xlsx"
```

Can anyone suggest a way I can just pick up the second file i.e. the one without ~$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `stringr` like this:

```
library(stringr)
list_of_files[!str_detect(list_of_files, "~$")]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` with `fixed`, `value` and `invert` as `TRUE`.

```
list_of_files <- c("//server/address1/address2/address3/Info/more/and more/and more again/R Code/~$class_xwalk_new.xlsx",
                   "//server/address1/address2/address3/Info/more/and more/and more again/R Code/class_xwalk_new.xlsx")

grep('~$', list_of_files, fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
```

Or `str_subset` from `stringr` :

```
stringr::str_subset(list_of_files, fixed('~$'), negate = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify a pattern that says your filename is exactly `class_xwalk_new.xlsx`, not a pattern saying it contains that string.  For example, `"^class_xwalk_new.xlsx$"`, so your search would be

```
list_of_files <- list.files(path = current_folder, 
                            pattern = "^class_xwalk_new.xlsx$", 
                            all.files = FALSE, 
                            recursive = FALSE,
                            full.names = TRUE)
```